# Copy file from Jenkins master to slave in Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have some windows slave at my Jenkins so I need to copy file to them in pipeline. I heard about Copy To Slave and Copy Artifact plugins, but they doesn't have pipeline syntax manual. So I don't know how to use them in pipeline.

Direct copy doesn't work.

```
def inputFile = input message: 'Upload file', parameters: [file(name: 'parameters.xml')]
new hudson.FilePath(new File("${ENV:WORKSPACE}\\parameters.xml")).copyFrom(inputFile)
```

This code returns and error:

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to copy /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/_dev/jobs/(TEST)job/builds/107/parameters.xml to d:\Jenkins\workspace\_dev\(TEST)job\parameters.xml
```

Is there any way to copy file from master to slave in Jenkins Pipeline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand `copyFrom` is executed on your Windows node, therefore the source path is not accessible.

I think you want to look into the `stash`/`unstash` steps ([Jenkins Pipeline: Basic Steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/)), which work across different nodes. Also this [example](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#unstash-different-dir) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps.

Comment: stash/unstash only works per job run, that is, the "stashed" data doesn't persist after the job runs.

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline DSL context runs on `master` node even that your write `node('someAgentName')` in your pipeline.

- Try to use [stash/unstash](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build), but it is bad for large files.
- Try [External Workspace Manager Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/external-workspace-manager/). It has 
  pipelines steps and good for large files.
- Try to use an intermediate storage. `archive()` and `sh("wget $url")` will be helpful.

Comment: Specifically, how is stash bad for large files? How would you define "large"?

I've read this on the cloudbees docs as well, but they don't answer my questions above. What's the deal, is it just a slow transfer, or is it buggy??

Just curious why I shouldn't stash a 150MB file on a master so I can unstash it from a slave agent in a subsequent stage. Seems much simpler than using External Workspace Manager.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I didn't RTFM closely enough: the stash step pipeline reference says "This is because stashed files are archived in a compressed TAR, and with large files this demands considerable on-master resources, particularly CPU time. There's not a hard stash size limit, but between 5-100 MB you should probably consider alternatives."

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to copy an executable to the test slave and to publish the test results, this is easy to do without the Copy to Slave plugin.

A shared folder should be created on each test slave (normal Windows shared folder).

After build: Build script copies the executable to the shared directory on each slave. A simple batch script using `copy` command is sufficient for this.

```
stage ('Copy to slaves') {
    steps {
        bat 'call "copy-to-slave.bat"'
    }
}
```

During test: The test script copies the executable to another directory and runs it.

After test: Post-build action "Publish Robot Framework test results" can be used to report the test results. It is not necessary to copy the test result files back to the master first.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend on `Pipeline: Phoenix AutoTest` plugin

Jenkins plugin website:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/phoenix-autotest/#documentation

GitHub repository of plugin:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/phoenix-autotest-plugin